# android soft keyboard backspace button not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, backspace, soft-keyboard

I want to take control of soft keyboard appering. So I have override EditText class and method onCheckIsTextEditor.

```
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return MenuActivity.expanded;
}
```

And after it everything works fine except delete/backspace button. When I press it nothing change. Also when I set onClickListener to my editText i can see that every click except delete fire this listener.

```
public void setOnBackSpaceListener(){
    this.setOnKeyListener((view, i, keyEvent) -> {
        Log.d("AAA -> ", String.valueOf(keyEvent.getKeyCode()));
        return false;
    });
}
```

So it's look like android think there was no click and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption that you are **implementing** `View.OnKeyListener` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.  Are you passing your listener to the view you would like to capture the event from?

In this case, it will be:

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
```